# "Bad press" in one word

Tags: word-choice, word-request, expressions

I'm looking for a single word (noun), rather informal, that would fit here:

> The team is getting a lot of … for losing the last two matches`

Comment: Why? *Bad press* is so common it reads like one word.

Comment: Why is a valid word-request receiving a close vote?

Comment: Because one sentence does not a context make. It's also searchable in dictionaries such as [MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/a-bad-good-press)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Criticism
- Opprobrium
- Stick (informal, British)

Comment: yes, but to the original poster, *bad press* reads like one word, it is such a common combination. *Criticism* and *opprobrium* take longer to say, and most native speakers don't know what the latter means and it is not at all informal.

Comment: @colin - I like `stick` but is there anything more universal there (not only British)?

Comment: There's American "flack" (pestering criticism) though it's probably moribund slang by now. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=getting+a+lot+of+flack&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgetting%20a%20lot%20of%20flack%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I hear *flak* reasonably often.  ("flak" being the more common spelling than "flack", at least here in the US - fun fact: it comes from the German "**Fl**ieger**a**bwehr**k**anone")  ["Getting flak" is common, but "taking flak" or "catching flak" are actually gaining in popularity.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catching+flak%2Cgetting+flak%2Ctaking+flak&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccatching%20flak%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgetting%20flak%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaking%20flak%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

> Flak

Defined as:

> strong criticism.
>   "you must be strong enough to take the flak if things go wrong"

Answer (score 0):

While I certainly agree with @Colin's answer of "Criticism" as perhaps the most common word to fit your sentence, you specifically asked for an answer that is "rather informal." For that case, I would use the word "crap."  Note that this is *extremely* informal, bordering on the vulgar or offensive.  It's something that would be said to your friends, but never to a broadcast audience or printed in a newspaper.

Comment: or *shite* or many things. Kind of hard to answer a question that gives only a sentence as context.

Comment: To, me, _crap_ doesn't fit in that sentence.